# Каков порядок выполнения запроса в Postgresql ( для понимания оптимизации запросов)

Tags: postgresql

Вот например, такой запрос

```sql
SELECT *
FROM employees emp
WHERE start_date BETWEEN '2019-04-01' AND '2019-04-30' where emp.dep = 'book' ;
```

Каким образом СУБД читает запрос?
Я предполагал (на основе некоторой информации в сети), что  СУБД начинает чтение запроса с конца.

Мне предложили оптимизацию : поменять местами  **where emp.dep = 'book'** и  **BETWEEN**

Каково ваше мнение в этом запросе ? Будет ли от этой перемены польза ?

Comment: От перестановки местами чего либо в запросе план выполнения не меняется. Оптимизатор анализирует весь запрос целиком, смотрит наличие подходящих индексов, оценивает статистику распределения значений в базе (которую собирает analyze) и еще много разных факторов. После чего уже строит оптимальный с его точки зрения план выполнения (который кстати можно посмотреть с помощью explain)

Comment: https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgresql/9.6/planner-optimizer

Comment: *Мне предложили оптимизацию* Вам предложили откровенную глупость. *Каким образом СУБД читает запрос?* План выполнения может вообще не соотноситься с текстом. Например, при некоторых обстоятельствах (особенностях запроса) условие в HAVING clause может быть обработано ещё до группировки записей - хотя формально выражение в HAVING в принципе не существует до выполнения группировки.